# Netbeans 6.8 missing Interactive Ruby Window

Tags: ruby, netbeans6.8

I installed Netbeans IDE 6.8 today to use it while learning Ruby.
Here the specifications:

> Product Version: NetBeans IDE 6.8
>   (Build 200912041610)
>
> Java: 1.6.0_17; Java HotSpot(TM)
>   Client VM 14.3-b01
>
> System: Windows XP version 5.1 running
>   on x86; Cp1252; en_US (nb)

So I created my first Ruby project and am able to run the program.
According to the documentation I should also be able to open an Interactive Ruby Window from Windows/Other/, but in my case that menu only contains [Exception Reporter, CSS Preview and CSS Stylebuilder].

This is the case no matter if I use JRuby or Ruby 1.8 as my Ruby Platform.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Although I could resort to the interactive console that comes native with the Ruby installation I would prefer to have it integrated in my IDE.

So if anyone knows how to resolve this issue, even if it means going back one version of Netbeans I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

right-click on your Ruby project and then select Ruby Shell(IRB)

Comment: Thanks, that did it. 
I assume they changed how to get to the shell without documenting the change?

Comment: I really have no idea, but it's good that you file a bug or notify them about it